# SQL Statement to Public Function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query that gives me the Current Employee Rate based on the WorkDay:

```
(Select Top 1 T1.Rate FROM tblERates as T1
WHERE T1.EMPID = tblPayroll.EMPID And T1.EffectiveDate <= tblPayroll.WorkDay
ORDER BY T1.EMPID asc, T1.EffectiveDate desc)
```

The project is growing. I need to return the Employee Rate on different Forms/Reports so I want to convert this SQL to a Public Function.

I tried this:

```
Public Function fncERate(EID As Integer, WD As Date) As Double

    Dim intERate As Double
    Dim intWD As String

    intWD = "#" & Format(WD, "m/d/yyyy") & "#"

    intERate = "SELECT TOP 1 Rate" _
                & "FROM tblERates" _
                & "WHERE EMPID = EID And EffectiveDate <= intWD" _
                & "ORDER BY EMPID asc;"
    fncERate = intERate

End Function
```

I get a "type mismatch error".

Comment: `intERate` is defined as `Double` and you are assigning a string to it.

Comment: There's a big gap between having some SQL and getting the output from the SQL.  Don't you have a database somewhere you need to talk to?  Also your SQL has no spaces between (eg) "Rate" and "FROM"

Comment: _Don't you have a database somewhere you need to talk to?_ I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't know what you are passing in for the date, but it would probably be easier to type it as a string.
Also, you need to terminate your SQL to separate it from the variables. For instance "WHERE EMPID = EID And EffectiveDate <= intWD"" should be "WHERE EMPID = " & EID &" And EffectiveDate <= " & intWD
Oh, and please don't call "intWD" "intWD" if it is a string. Call it "sWD" or "strWD" to indicate it's type.Also, when you are debugging, keep in mind that typing a date in like "9/1/2019" isn't going to be the same as getting it from a Date Picker that inserted into a DB date field.

Comment: What is your function intended to do?  Return some SQL (which it will do if you change the return type to String and add in the missing spaces) or actually return a Double which is the result of executing that SQL?

Comment: As Brian & Tim have pointed out, you need to assign the SQL statement to a string and execute the string like so - sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE AText = '" & Me.MyCombo.Column(1) & "'"

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset     
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit I came up with this:

```
Public Function fncERate(EID As Integer, WD As Date) As Double


    Dim intERate As String
    Dim intWD As String
    Dim intEID As Integer


    intWD = "#" & Format(WD, "m/d/yyyy") & "#"

    intERate = "SELECT TOP 1 [Rate]" & _
                " FROM tblERates" & _
                " WHERE [EMPID] = " & EID & " And [EffectiveDate] <= " & intWD & " " & _
                " ORDER BY [EMPID] asc;"

    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(intERate)
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            fncERate = .Fields(0)
        End If
    End With


End Function
```

Comment: There is no point in ordering by `EMPID`, as only one employee is selected. But it should be sorted by `EffectiveDate DESC` to get the newest date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you lack spaces in your sql syntax
A little tip for quick dev

Press **Ctrl+G** to open execution pane while debugging and type

> ?intERate

to print the value of your variable
then you can just copy paste the sql and try it directly